# Google Trends for Play Store

Tags: google-play-store, google-trends

Is it possible to monitor top search phrases and trends for Google Play Store (mobile apps) similar as we can do for regular web search terms via https://trends.google.com/trends/?geo=US ?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please show what you tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Thanks for your interest @Ruben. I've checked https://newsinitiative.withgoogle.com/training/lessons?tool=Google%20Trends&image=trends (unfortunately without luck). Googling also didn't provide any useful services (beside articles on specified trends).